# How can I store a very large text file into an array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very large text file with more than 10.000 entries. I need to store the data into an array, because I need to check and validate all the entries before storing everything in the mySQL database.

```
$file_path = $filename;
$linesArray = file($file_path);    
$properties = array();

foreach ($linesArray AS $line) {
    if (strlen($line) && $line[0] == '#') {
        $pdate = substr($line, 1);
        $date = rtrim($pdate);
        $formatted = DateTime::createFromFormat('* M d H:i:s T Y',$date);
    }
    if (false !== ($pos = strpos($line, '='))) {
        $prop=array();    
        $prop[trim(substr($line, 0, $pos))] = trim(substr($line, $pos + 1));
        $lineContArray = explode("=", $line);
        $identArray = explode(".", $lineContArray[0]);
        $ident = $identArray[0];
        $type = $identArray[1];     
        $value = trim($lineContArray[1]);
        $found = 0;
        for ($i=0; $i<count($properties); $i++) {
            if ($properties[$i]['number'] == $ident) {
                $properties[$i][$type]= $value;
                $found=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($found == 0) { 
            if (!empty($type)) { 
                $properties[] = array('number' => $ident, $type => $value); 
            } else { 
                $properties[] = array($ident => $value); 
            } 
        }
    }
}
var_dump($properties);
```

This works very well with files up to 3000 entries, but with larger files I get a blanc page.

Comment: There is no blank page without error ;) please take a look at the error log, i guess exceeded timelimit (if broswer), or definitely a allowed memory error

Comment: Hi, I am using: `error_reporting (E_ALL);ini_set ('display_errors', 'On');` at the beginning of my page, but still the page is blanc. Well it is not totally blanc, my headline is still there

Comment: you have to configure this via php.ini or .htaccess, depends on host. I guess you are not allowed to output the errors on your host. >ou should go for  you apache error_log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dumping the array after the whole file has been processed, you could dump in each iteration the element you are adding to that array. That way there is a flow of output:

```
        ...
        if ($found == 0) { 
            if (!empty($type)) { 
                $property = array('number' => $ident, $type => $value); 
            } else { 
                $property = array($ident => $value); 
            }
            // dump this line's result and a linebreak:
            var_dump($property);
            echo '<br>';
            $properties[] = $property;
        }
    }
}
// not needed anymore:
//var_dump($properties);
//
```

If the output still does not come through, add [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) in your code.

**Some comments on your code**

The last of the following lines in your code will produce a run-time error when processing a line that has an equal sign, but no preceding dot:

```
    $identArray = explode(".", $lineContArray[0]);
    $ident = $identArray[0];
    $type = $identArray[1];
```

The inner loop (`for ($i=0; $i<count($properties); $i++)`) is very inefficient. It would be better to make an associative array keyed by `$ident`, containing references to your `$properties` array. That way your look-up does not need a loop.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I got the output NULL NULL NULL.... So I changed your code a little bit:   `var_dump($properties);echo '<br>';
$property[] = $properties;` Now a get a result, but everything is confused, some entries I get 2 times, some I get three times

Comment: That change makes no sense, and is not what I intended, please use the code suggested and debug. If you get `NULL`, it means your code has put them in variables `$ident`, `$value` ... etc. But that is another question altogether. You were asking about getting output for large files...

Comment: sorry, I did a mistake, I tried again your code, now it is working. I can see the large file. So I get a result. But still, I get an entry which is unique 2 or three times instead of one time. But the most important for me is to know that an array is created. Thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome. I also added some further observations on your code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can use fread or fget for large file

This will be reading line by line

```
if ($handle = @fopen("inputfile.txt", "r")) {
    while (($readLine = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $readLine;
        //create an array according to the text data
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

For ref:-
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php